# How to add constraints programmatically using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to figure this out since last week without going any step further. Ok, so I need to apply some **constraints** ***programmatically*** in **Swift** to a `UIView` using this code:

```
var new_view:UIView! = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100));
new_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
view.addSubview(new_view);

var constX:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
self.view.addConstraint(constX);

var constY:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
self.view.addConstraint(constY);

var constW:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
self.view.addConstraint(constW);

var constH:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: new_view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
self.view.addConstraint(constH);
```

But Xcode returns this weird output:

```
2014-10-03 09:48:12.657 Test[35088:2454916] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea446830 UIView:0x7fa4ea429290.centerX == UIView:0x7fa4ea4470f0.centerX>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea4516c0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fa4ea429290.midX == + 50>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea452830 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fa4ea4470f0(375)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea446db0 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fa4ea4470f0]   (Names: '|':UIWindow:0x7fa4ea444b20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea446830 UIView:0x7fa4ea429290.centerX == UIView:0x7fa4ea4470f0.centerX>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
<UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

2014-10-03 09:48:12.658 Test[35088:2454916] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea44d160 UIView:0x7fa4ea429290.centerY == UIView:0x7fa4ea4470f0.centerY>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea451b30 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x7fa4ea429290.midY == + 50>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea44cf00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x7fa4ea4470f0(667)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea452700 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fa4ea4470f0]  (Names: '|':UIWindow:0x7fa4ea444b20 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa4ea44d160 UIView:0x7fa4ea429290.centerY == UIView:0x7fa4ea4470f0.centerY>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please paste error messages in as code blocks, not as quoted text.  That means you need to put four spaces at the beginning of each line, not a `>`.  I have fixed it for you this time.

Comment: you are missing "translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false"

Comment: You may want to use this awesome library for dynamic and simple constraints.         https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit

Comment: Make sure you see [On iOS, what are the differences between margins, edge insets, content insets, alignment rects, layout margins, anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796884/on-ios-what-are-the-differences-between-margins-edge-insets-content-insets-a/47614397#47614397). It will improve your decision making between margins, anchors, layoutguides...

Comment: here is the post that will explains how to add constrains through code: https://slicode.com/auto-layout-in-ios-explained-in-details-from-basics-part-2/

Answer (score 1251):

Do you plan to have a squared `UIView` of *width: 100* and *Height: 100* centered inside the `UIView` of an `UIViewController`? If so, you may try one of the 6 following Auto Layout styles (Swift 5 / iOS 12.2):

---

#### 1. Using `NSLayoutConstraint` initializer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100).isActive = true
}
```

---

#### 2. Using Visual Format Language

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let views = ["view": view!, "newView": newView]
    let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[view]-(<=0)-[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[view]-(<=0)-[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
    view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
    view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let views = ["view": view!, "newView": newView]
    let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[view]-(<=0)-[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[view]-(<=0)-[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(horizontalConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalConstraints)
}
```

---

#### 3. Using a mix of `NSLayoutConstraint` initializer and Visual Format Language

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let views = ["newView": newView]
    let widthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let heightConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints(widthConstraints)
    view.addConstraints(heightConstraints)
    view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let views = ["newView": newView]
    let widthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let heightConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(widthConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(heightConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let views = ["newView": newView]
    let widthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let heightConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[newView(100)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(widthConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(heightConstraints)
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

---

#### 4. Using `UIView.AutoresizingMask`

Note: Springs and Struts will be translated into corresponding auto layout constraints at runtime.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)

    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    newView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    newView.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleLeftMargin, UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleRightMargin, UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleTopMargin, UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleBottomMargin]
}
```

---

#### 5. Using `NSLayoutAnchor`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)
    
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let horizontalConstraint = newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    let verticalConstraint = newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    let widthConstraint = newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    let heightConstraint = newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)
    
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let horizontalConstraint = newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
    let verticalConstraint = newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    let widthConstraint = newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    let heightConstraint = newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let newView = UIView()
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(newView)
    
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
}
```

---

#### 6. Using `intrinsicContentSize` and `NSLayoutAnchor`

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
    
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let newView = CustomView()
        newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.addSubview(newView)
        
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
    }
    
}
```

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to animate the anchor style constraints?

Comment: I didn't know about the option 5 / anchor style, I really like it because it fits best with the model of what I'm trying to do. But because I don't tend to update the constraints after they've been added I use a shorthand that activates them at the same time as creating them: e.g. `newView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true`

Comment: if you want offsets, use this for example         let h = newView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor, constant: 80) or         let w = updatesAvailablePopover.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 100)

Comment: @MathewS by using the shorthand style, is it possible to change the constraint later on? How to change it? I have been trying to find an answer online but I just can't find it.

Comment: @JoeHuang no, the short hand doesn't work if you want to change the constraint in the future because the shorthand is creating a new constraint. You'll need to use the anchor style Imanou uses in the answer if you want a reference to update a constraint in the future :)

Comment: I am trying to implement first method not working
please let me know what is the issue

Comment: @Imanou, thanks. Your anchor example let me constrain a collection of UIButtons but when these didn't work, I tried a different approach. That caused the constraint not to work. You might like to check it out if you have time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650951/if-were-in-the-real-pre-commit-handler-we-cant-actually-add-any-new-fences-due

Comment: For the option of using anchors, why not do  `view.addConstraints([...])` instead of `NSLayoutConstraint.activate([...])`

Comment: What's with iOS having different setup for constraints? Any benefits on learning all of them or just stick to one?

Comment: amazed examples

Comment: Don't forget the `newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` part! That took me a while to see.

Comment: I don't know if the code above stopped working - but I get  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for <UILabel: 0x7fb50c43e190; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x600001014320>>: Unknown layout attribute' running the example code as is

Comment: this helped after spending 3 hours for trying and failed

Answer (score 295):

It helps me to learn visually, so this is a supplemental answer.

## Boilerplate code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)

    // Add constraints code here
    // ...
}
```

Each of the following examples are independent of the others.

## Pin left edge

`myView.leading = leadingMargin + 20`

[image]

**Method 1: Anchor Style**

```
let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

- In addition to `leadingAnchor`, there is also `trailingAnchor`, `topAnchor`, and `bottomAnchor`.

**Method 2: NSLayoutConstraint Style**

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
```

- In addition to `.leading` there is also `.trailing`, `.top`, and `.bottom`.
- In addition to `.leadingMargin` there is also `.trailingMargin`, `.topMargin`, and `.bottomMargin`.

## Set Width and Height

`width = 200`
`height = 100`

[image]

**Method 1: Anchor Style**

```
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

**Method 2: NSLayoutConstraint Style**

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100).isActive = true
```

## Center in container

`myView.centerX = centerX`
`myView.centerY = centerY`

[image]

**Method 1: Anchor Style**

```
myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

**Method 2: NSLayoutConstraint Style**

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

## Notes

- Anchor style is the preferred method over `NSLayoutConstraint` Style, however it is only available from iOS 9, so if you are supporting iOS 8 then you should still use `NSLayoutConstraint` Style.
- The examples above showed just the one or two constraints that were being focused on. However, in order to properly place `myView` in my test project I needed to have four constraints.

## Further Reading

- [Programmatically Creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html) documentation

Comment: Very nice! One small note: only one of `leading` vs. `centerX` constraints should be specified.

Comment: @CyberDude, yes, you are correct. I meant for all of the examples above to be independent of each other, not adding all of the constraints to the same view. That is not as clear as I would have liked, though.

Comment: You left out the necessary `addConstraint()` on `view` in order to make the layoutconstraints register.

Answer (score 51):

If you want to fill your super view then I suggest the swifty way:

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let attributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.top, .bottom, .right, .left]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(attributes.map {
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: $0, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view.superview, attribute: $0, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
})
```

Other wise if you need non equal constraints check out NSLayoutAnchor as of iOS 9.  Its often much easier to read that using NSLayoutConstraint directly:

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.topAnchor).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

Comment: Based on this [moment of WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/219/?time=326). It's generally not efficient to activate constraints one by one ie doing `isActive = true` is not always a good idea. It's better and more performant to group the related constraints into one and activate them all at once using `NSLayoutConstraint.activate`.

Answer (score 38):

We can easily do this with in swift 5.1

**setup 1**

- subview align to view center
- subview width height set using float

  ```
   view.addSubview(myView1)
   myView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       myView1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
       myView1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
       myView1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
       myView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
   ])
  ```

**setup 2**

- subview align to view leading and top anchor
- subview width set using view width height

  ```
       view.addSubview(myView2)
       myView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

       NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           myView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant: 16),
           myView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,constant: 16),
           myView2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3),
           myView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3)
       ])
  ```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 33):

Constraints for multiple views in playground.

**swift 3+**

```
  var yellowView: UIView!
    var redView: UIView!

    override func loadView() {

        // UI

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        yellowView = UIView()
        yellowView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(yellowView)

        redView = UIView()
        redView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(redView)

        // Layout
        redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        yellowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            yellowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            yellowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            yellowView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            yellowView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),

            redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
            redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant: -20),
            redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
            ])

        self.view = view
    }
```

> In my opinion xcode playground is the best place for learning adding
>   constraints programmatically.

[image: Playground image]

Answer (score 18):

Basically it involved 3 steps

```
fileprivate func setupName() { 

    lblName.text = "Hello world"

    // Step 1
    lblName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Step 2
    self.view.addSubview(lblName)

    //Step 3
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        lblName.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        lblName.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
    ])
}
```

This puts label "hello world" in center of screen.

Please refer link [Autolayout constraints programmatically](https://medium.com/@avinashraamireddy/autolayout-constraint-programmatically-in-swift4-ios-42077bfa1a69)

Answer (score 15):

The problem, as the error message suggests, is that you have constraints of type `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints` that conflict with your explicit constraints, because `new_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to true.

This is the default setting for views you create in code.  You can turn it off like this:

```
var new_view:UIView! = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
new_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Also, your width and height constraints are weird.  If you want the view to have a constant width, this is the proper way:

```
new_view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
    item:new_view, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
    toItem:nil, attribute:NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
    multiplier:0, constant:100))
```

(Replace 100 by the width you want it to have.)

If your deployment target is iOS 9.0 or later, you can use this shorter code:

```
new_view.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100).active = true
```

Anyway, for a layout like this (fixed size and centered in parent view), it would be simpler to use the autoresizing mask and let the system translate the mask into constraints:

```
var new_view:UIView! = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
new_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
view.addSubview(new_view);

// This is the default setting but be explicit anyway...
new_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

new_view.autoresizingMask = [ .FlexibleTopMargin, .FlexibleBottomMargin,
    .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleRightMargin ]

new_view.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY)
```

Note that using autoresizing is perfectly legitimate even when you're also using autolayout. (UIKit still uses autoresizing in lots of places internally.) The problem is that it's difficult to apply additional constraints to a view that is using autoresizing.

Comment: if UIKit uses autoresizing internally could that explain misbehaviour of constraints that are anchored in the centre ? When I organise a collection of UIButtons as a subclass of UIview the anchor constraints appear to work but they do not work when I organise them as functions within a viewcontroller. If you can spare the time you might have a look at this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650951/if-were-in-the-real-pre-commit-hand‌ ler-we-cant-actually-add-any-new-fences-due]

Comment: No, that doesn't explain the misbehavior of your code.

Answer (score 14):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let redView: UIView = {

    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupViews()
    setupAutoLayout()
}

func setupViews() {

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(redView)
}

func setupAutoLayout() {

    // Available from iOS 9 commonly known as Anchoring System for AutoLayout...
    redView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    redView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

    redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

    // You can also modified above last two lines as follows by commenting above & uncommenting below lines...
    // redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    // redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 }
}
```

[image]

**Type of Constraints**

```
 /*
// regular use
1.leftAnchor
2.rightAnchor
3.topAnchor
// intermediate use
4.widthAnchor
5.heightAnchor
6.bottomAnchor
7.centerXAnchor
8.centerYAnchor
// rare use
9.leadingAnchor
10.trailingAnchor
etc. (note: very project to project)
*/
```

Comment: Don't forget to add, 

youViewName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Answer (score 9):

Auto layout is realized by applying constraints on images. Use NSLayoutConstraint. It is possible to implement an ideal and beautiful design on all devices. Please try the code below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
myImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
myImageView.image = UIImage(named:"sample_dog")!
myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 10
self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
        
view.removeConstraints(view.constraints)


view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
item: myImageView,
attribute: .top,
relatedBy: .equal,
toItem: view,
attribute: .top,
multiplier: 1,
constant:100)
    
)

view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
item: myImageView,
attribute: .centerX,
relatedBy: .equal,
toItem: view,
attribute: .centerX,
multiplier: 1,
constant:0)
)
    
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
item: myImageView,
attribute: .height,
relatedBy: .equal,
toItem: view,
attribute: .width,
multiplier: 0.5,
constant:40))
    
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
item: myImageView,
attribute: .width,
relatedBy: .equal,
toItem: view,
attribute: .width,
multiplier: 0.5,
constant:40))
    
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

the following code works for me in this scenario: an UIImageView forced landscape.

```
    imagePreview!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imagePreview!.isExclusiveTouch = true
    imagePreview!.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    
    // Remove all constraints
    imagePreview!.removeAllConstraints()
    
    // Add the new constraints
    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    imagePreview!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imagePreview!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    imagePreview!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    imagePreview!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
```

where removeAllConstraints is an extension

```
extension UIView {
    
    func removeAllConstraints() {
        var _superview = self.superview
        
        func removeAllConstraintsFromView(view: UIView) { for c in view.constraints { view.removeConstraint(c) } }
        
        while let superview = _superview {
            for constraint in superview.constraints {
                
                if let first = constraint.firstItem as? UIView, first == self {
                    superview.removeConstraint(constraint)
                }
                
                if let second = constraint.secondItem as? UIView, second == self {
                    superview.removeConstraint(constraint)
                }
            }
            
            _superview = superview.superview
        }
        
        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    }
}
```

Comment: A few suggestions: I would never force unwrap something. Always stick a guard before accessing an optional, otherwise you're gonna get some crashes. Also, you shouldn't need to remove all constraints. That's a waste of processing power and can cause issues. Just add the constraints you need when the view is loading, either in viewDidLoad or init function.

Answer (score 7):

If you find the above to be ugly. You should consider using a DSL for constraints. Such as [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)
Makes constraint API much more user-friendly

```
view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.edges.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Would like to add some theoretical concept to  Imanou Petit’s answer, so that one can understand how auto layout works.**

To understand auto layout consider your view as **rubber's object** which is shrinked initially.

**To place an object on screen we need 4 mandatory things :**

- X coordinate of object (horizontal position).
- Y coordinate of object   (vertical position )
- Object’s Width
- Object’s Height.

1 **X coordinate:** There are multiple ways of giving x coordinates to a view.

*Such as Leading constraint, Trailing constraint , Horizontally centre
etc.*

2 **Y coordinate:** There are multiple ways of giving y coordinates to a view :

*Such as Top constraint, Bottom constraint , Vertical centre etc.*

3 **Object's width:** There are two ways of giving width constrain to a view :

*a. Add fixed width constraint (consider this constraint as iron rod of fixed width and you have hooked your rubber’s object horizontally with it so rubber’s object don’t shrink or expand)*

***b. Do not add any width constraint but add x coordinate constraint to both end of view trailing and leading, these two constraints will expand/shrink your rubber’s object by pulling/pushing it from both end, leading and trailing.***

4 **Object's height:** Similar to width, there are two ways of giving height constraint to a view as well :

*a. Add fixed height constraint (consider this constraints as iron rod of fixed height and you have hooked your rubber’s object vertically with it so rubber’s object don’t shrink or expand)*

***b. Do not add any height constraint but add x coordinate constraint to both end of view top and bottom, these two constraints will expand/shrink your rubber’s object pulling/pushing it from both end, top and bottom.***

Answer (score 6):

This is one way to adding constraints programmatically

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


let myLabel = UILabel()
        myLabel.labelFrameUpdate(label: myLabel, text: "Welcome User", font: UIFont(name: "times new roman", size: 40)!, textColor: UIColor.red, textAlignment: .center, numberOfLines: 0, borderWidth: 2.0, BorderColor: UIColor.red.cgColor)
        self.view.addSubview(myLabel)


         let myLabelhorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let myLabelverticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let mylabelLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let mylabelTrailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
        let myLabelheightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(\[myLabelhorizontalConstraint, myLabelverticalConstraint, myLabelheightConstraint,mylabelLeading,mylabelTrailing\])
}

extension UILabel
{
    func labelFrameUpdate(label:UILabel,text:String = "This is sample Label",font:UIFont = UIFont(name: "times new roman", size: 20)!,textColor:UIColor = UIColor.red,textAlignment:NSTextAlignment = .center,numberOfLines:Int = 0,borderWidth:CGFloat = 2.0,BorderColor:CGColor = UIColor.red.cgColor){
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = text
        label.font = font
        label.textColor = textColor
        label.textAlignment = textAlignment
        label.numberOfLines = numberOfLines
        label.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

it is a little different in xcode 7.3.1. this is what i come up with

```
   // creating the view
        let newView = UIView()
        newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(newView)

        // creating the constraint 

        // attribute and relation cannot be set directyl you need to create a cariable of them
        let layout11 = NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX
        let layout21 = NSLayoutRelation.Equal
        let layout31 = NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY
        let layout41 = NSLayoutAttribute.Width
        let layout51 = NSLayoutAttribute.Height
        let layout61 = NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute

        // defining all the constraint
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: layout11, relatedBy: layout21, toItem: view, attribute: layout11, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: layout31, relatedBy: layout21, toItem: view, attribute: layout31, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: layout41, relatedBy: layout21, toItem: nil, attribute: layout61, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: layout51, relatedBy: layout21, toItem: nil, attribute: layout61, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

        // adding all the constraint
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizontalConstraint,verticalConstraint,widthConstraint,heightConstraint])
```

Comment: translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false   :))

Answer (score 4):

```
    var xCenterConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
    var yCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

 xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: (Your view NAme), attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            self.view.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)

 yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: (Your view Name), attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            self.view.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
```

Comment: Please explain the code and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this elegant `UIView` extension for constraints. You can do constraints easy as:

```
 - firstView.coverWholeSuperview()
 - firstView.constraints(size: CGSize(width: 44, height: 44), centerX: view.centerXAnchor, centerY: view.centerXAnchor)
 - firstView.constraints(top: view.topAnchor, 
                         leading: secondView.leadingAnchor, 
                         bottom: view.bottomAnchor, 
                         trailing: secondView.trailingAnchor, 
                         padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 12, left: 12, bottom: 12, right: 12))
```

Here is extension, just copy it to your project.

```
extension UIView {
    /// Attaches all sides of the receiver to its parent view
    func coverWholeSuperview(margin: CGFloat = 0.0) {
        let view = superview
        layoutAttachTop(to: view, margin: margin)
        layoutAttachBottom(to: view, margin: margin)
        layoutAttachLeading(to: view, margin: margin)
        layoutAttachTrailing(to: view, margin: margin)

    }

    /// Attaches the top of the current view to the given view's top if it's a superview of the current view
    /// or to it's bottom if it's not (assuming this is then a sibling view).
    @discardableResult
    func layoutAttachTop(to: UIView? = nil, margin: CGFloat = 0.0) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

        let view: UIView? = to ?? superview
        let isSuperview = view == superview
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                                            toItem: view, attribute: isSuperview ? .top : .bottom, multiplier: 1.0,
                                            constant: margin)
        superview?.addConstraint(constraint)

        return constraint
    }

    /// Attaches the bottom of the current view to the given view
    @discardableResult
    func layoutAttachBottom(to: UIView? = nil, margin: CGFloat = 0.0, priority: UILayoutPriority? = nil) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

        let view: UIView? = to ?? superview
        let isSuperview = (view == superview) || false
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,
                                            toItem: view, attribute: isSuperview ? .bottom : .top, multiplier: 1.0,
                                            constant: -margin)
        if let priority = priority {
            constraint.priority = priority
        }
        superview?.addConstraint(constraint)

        return constraint
    }

    /// Attaches the leading edge of the current view to the given view
    @discardableResult
    func layoutAttachLeading(to: UIView? = nil, margin: CGFloat = 0.0) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

        let view: UIView? = to ?? superview
        let isSuperview = (view == superview) || false
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal,
                                            toItem: view, attribute: isSuperview ? .leading : .trailing, multiplier: 1.0,
                                            constant: margin)
        superview?.addConstraint(constraint)

        return constraint
    }

    /// Attaches the trailing edge of the current view to the given view
    @discardableResult
    func layoutAttachTrailing(to: UIView? = nil, margin: CGFloat = 0.0, priority: UILayoutPriority? = nil) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

        let view: UIView? = to ?? superview
        let isSuperview = (view == superview) || false
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal,
                                            toItem: view, attribute: isSuperview ? .trailing : .leading, multiplier: 1.0,
                                            constant: -margin)
        if let priority = priority {
            constraint.priority = priority
        }
        superview?.addConstraint(constraint)

        return constraint
    }

    // For anchoring View
    struct AnchoredConstraints {
        var top, leading, bottom, trailing, width, height, centerX, centerY: NSLayoutConstraint?
    }

    @discardableResult
    func constraints(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil,
                trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero,
                centerX: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, centerY: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil,
                centerXOffset: CGFloat = 0, centerYOffset: CGFloat = 0) -> AnchoredConstraints {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var anchoredConstraints = AnchoredConstraints()

        if let top = top {
            anchoredConstraints.top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            anchoredConstraints.leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            anchoredConstraints.bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            anchoredConstraints.trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            anchoredConstraints.width = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            anchoredConstraints.height = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
        }

        if let centerX = centerX {
            anchoredConstraints.centerX = centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerX, constant: centerXOffset)
        }

        if let centerY = centerY {
            anchoredConstraints.centerY = centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerY, constant: centerYOffset)
        }

        [anchoredConstraints.top, anchoredConstraints.leading, anchoredConstraints.bottom,
         anchoredConstraints.trailing, anchoredConstraints.width,
         anchoredConstraints.height, anchoredConstraints.centerX,
         anchoredConstraints.centerY].forEach { $0?.isActive = true }

        return anchoredConstraints
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding all defined constraints to `self.view` which is wrong, as width and height constraint should be added to your `newView`.

Also, as I understand you want to set constant width and height 100:100.
In this case you should change your code to:

```
var constW = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, 
    attribute: .Width, 
    relatedBy: .Equal, 
    toItem: nil, 
    attribute: .NotAnAttribute, 
    multiplier: 1, 
    constant: 100)
newView.addConstraint(constW)

var constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, 
    attribute: .Height, 
    relatedBy: .Equal, 
    toItem: nil, 
    attribute: .NotAnAttribute, 
    multiplier: 1, 
    constant: 100)
newView.addConstraint(constH)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Snapkit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) to set constraints programmatically.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let rectView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        rectView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(rectView)

        rectView.snp.makeConstraints {
          $0.center.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by constrains automatically created from autoresizing mask, they are created because UIView property **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints** is true by default.

Consider using [BoxView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/BoxView) to get rid of all manual constraint creation boilerplate, and make your code concize and readable. To make layout in question with BoxView is very easy:

```
boxView.items = [
   new_view.boxed.centerX().centerY().relativeWidth(1.0).relativeHeight(1.0)
]
```