# Programmatically Add CenterX/CenterY Constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UITableViewController that doesn't display any sections if there is nothing to show. I've added a label to indicate to the user that there is nothing to display with this code:

```
label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 250, 100))
label.text = "Nothing to show"
self.tableView.addSubview(label)
```

But now, I want it to be centered Horizontally and Vertically. Normally, I would choose the two options highlighted (plus ones for height and width) in the screenshot:

[image]

I've tried the following code to add the constraints but the app crashes with error:

```
label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 250, 100))
label.text = "Nothing to show"

let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

label.addConstraint(xConstraint)
label.addConstraint(yConstraint)
```

error:

```
When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2014-12-23 08:17:36.755 [982:227877] *** Assertion failure in -[UILabel _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.21/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:560
```

The label should always center horizontally and vertically because the app supports rotation of the device.

What am I doing wrong? How do I add these constraints successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: I AM CREATING THIS IN VIEWDIDLOAD.

Comment: I don't see the line where you add the label as a subview to some other view. It's important you do that before adding constraints to it.

Comment: I am: label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 250, 100))
label.text = "Nothing to show"
self.tableView.addSubview(label)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

**Update for Swift 3/Swift 4:**

As of iOS 8, you can and should activate your constraints by setting their `isActive` property to `true`.  This enables the constraints to add themselves to the proper views.  You can activate multiple constraints at once by passing an array containing the constraints to `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()`

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
label.text = "Nothing to show"
label.textAlignment = .center
label.backgroundColor = .red  // Set background color to see if label is centered
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.tableView.addSubview(label)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 250)

let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
                                          toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)

let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([widthConstraint, heightConstraint, xConstraint, yConstraint])
```

**Better Solution:**

Since this question was originally answered, layout anchors were introduced making it much easier to create the constraints.  In this example I create the constraints and immediately activate them:

```
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

or the same using `NSLayoutConstraint.activate()`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250),
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.centerXAnchor),
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.centerYAnchor)
])
```

Note:  Always add your subviews to the view hierarchy *before* creating and activating the constraints.

---

**Original Answer:**

The constraints make reference to `self.tableView`.  Since you are adding the label as a subview of `self.tableView`, the constraints need to be added to the "common ancestor":

```
   self.tableView.addConstraint(xConstraint)
   self.tableView.addConstraint(yConstraint)
```

---

As @mustafa and @kcstricks pointed out in the comments, you need to set  `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`.  When you do this, you also need to specify the `width` and `height` of the label with constraints because the frame no longer is used.  Finally, you also should set the `textAlignment` to `.Center` so that your text is centered in your label.

```
    var  label = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    label.text = "Nothing to show"
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()  // Set background color to see if label is centered
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.tableView.addSubview(label)

    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 250)
    label.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
    label.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.tableView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    self.tableView.addConstraint(xConstraint)
    self.tableView.addConstraint(yConstraint)
```

Answer (score 40):

## Center in container

[image]

The code below does the same thing as centering in the Interface Builder.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set up the view
    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(myView)

    // Add code for one of the constraint methods below
    // ...
}
```

**Method 1: Anchor Style**

```
myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

**Method 2: NSLayoutConstraint Style**

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

## Notes

- Anchor style is the preferred method over `NSLayoutConstraint` Style, however it is only available from iOS 9, so if you are supporting iOS 8 then you should still use `NSLayoutConstraint` Style.
- You will also need to add length and width constraints.
- My full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263784/3681880).

Answer (score 15):

In Swift 5 it looks like this:

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 14):

The ObjectiveC equivalent is:

```
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [[myView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor] setActive:YES];

    [[myView.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor] setActive:YES];
```

Comment: best one for me, Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Programmatically you can do it by adding the following constraints.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraintHorizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self  
                                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                                         toItem:self.superview 
                                                                      attribute:attribute 
                                                                     multiplier:1.0f 
                                                                       constant:0.0f];

NSLayoutConstraint *constraintVertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY 
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:self.superview 
                                                                        attribute:attribute 
                                                                       multiplier:1.0f
                                                                         constant:0.0f];
```

Comment: Please swap constraintVertical with constraintHorizontal - it's confusing

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about this question being specifically about a tableview, and you'd just like to center one view on top of another view here's to do it:

```
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    parentView.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    parentView.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution for me was to create a `UILabel` and add it to the `UIButton` as a subview. Finally I added a constraint to center it within the button.

```
UILabel * myTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 75)];
myTextLabel.text = @"Some Text";
myTextLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

[myButton addSubView:myTextLabel];

// Add Constraints
[[myTextLabel centerYAnchor] constraintEqualToAnchor:myButton.centerYAnchor].active = true;
[[myTextLabel centerXAnchor] constraintEqualToAnchor:myButton.centerXAnchor].active = true;
```