# Why add UIView in contentView center always not in center?

Tags: ios, swift

I want add a UIView in its contentView center.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    contentView.addSubview(view)
    view.center = contentView.center

}
```

But the result is

[image]

Did I forget something?

**Update** 
thanks @Wain's tip, Constrain work.
According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27624927/6006588

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(view)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
                                             toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
                                              toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
     let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([heightConstraint,  widthConstraint,xConstraint, yConstraint])
}
```

I think I use constraint in StoryBoard to contentView (centerX , centerY , Equal Width , Equal Height to superView). 
The contentView will have incorrect frame size in ViewDidLoad.
And when I set view.center = contentView.center it don't work.
I need use constraint programmatically to set view's position.
Thanks.

Comment: Yout code is working fine for me in 6S simulator but not 6S+. How ever i have implemented it by code. it is working fine for all simulators

Comment: Why aren't you using constraints?

Comment: @Wain . The reason is I need to add dynamic views whose receive from server in a scrollView. And I need add button in the each of view's center like Youtube play button. Do you have any good idea?

Comment: yes, constraints... try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
```

Then add this to viewDidLoad

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
let contentView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
view.center = contentView.center
contentView.addSubview(view)
self.view.addSubview(contentView)
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It work. But Why reset contentView frame? I prefer set constraint in StoryBoard. Is constraint let view haven't correct size in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((contentView.frame.size.width-100)/2,(contentView.frame.size.height-100)/2,100,100))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    contentView.addSubview(view)
```