# Can't add constraints to video programmatically

Tags: swift, video

I am trying to programmatically constraint a video into the center of the page. My AV controller is called `avPlayerController` .

I have already given its x and y values along with the width and height:

`avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 36 , y: 20, width: 343, height: 264)`

So how do i center it?

I HAVE TRIED: [Programmatically Add CenterX/CenterY Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624133/programmatically-add-centerx-centery-constraints)

But, as you can guess it did not work :(

Here is my code:

```
 super.viewDidLoad()
        let filepath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "rockline", ofType: "mp4")
        let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filepath!)


        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)


        let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        avPlayerController.player = avPlayer
        avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 36 , y: 20, width: 343, height: 264)

        //  hide/show control
        avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        // play video

        avPlayerController.player?.play()
        self.view.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
    avPlayerController.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Setting the frame is not the same as setting a constraint. The layout is actually done in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: It's not that you are asking many questions, you are deleting questions and re-asking them! Two hours ago you ask this, and like @Pruthvikar, I commented that you shouldn't be setting frames. I also detailed the three things to do and *you* commented back asking for code. I can do that, but will you delete this question too?

Comment: so sorry i wont i promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, with explanation.

- Always remember that if you are using auto layout constraints, *do not* set frames. The layout engine will walk all over them. If you are instantiating your view in code, don't set a frame, or if necessary, it communicates things best if you set the frame to `CGRect.zero`.
- Understand the view life cycle. Specifically, you *can* set your constraints in `viewDidLoad`, where they should be created only once.
- Remember to set the auto resizing mask to `false`. This is the most common error when you learning auto layout in code.
- There are actually three ways to create constraints, and a few ways to activate them. In your question, I think the easiest way is to use anchors.

Here's an example of centering a view (*any* view) with a width of 343 and a height of 264:

```
let myView = UIView()    // note, I'm not setting any frame

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 343.0).isActive = true
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 264.0).isActive = true
    myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

That's all there is to it! BUT....

I'd suggest one more thing. Don't use constants in setting the height and width. That's not being "adaptive". Your 4 inch iPhone SE has a screen size of 568x320, where this may look centered and large enough. But on an iPhone Plus with a screen size of 736x414 it may be pretty small. (To say nothing of a 12.9 inch iPad Pro!)

Notice how my code uses the *superview* for the centerX/centerY anchors. (And instead of `equalToConstant` it's `equalTo`.) Do the same with the width and height. Through the use of `multiplier` and `constant`, along with `UILayoutGuide`s, you can make your layouts adapt to whatever screen size Apple throws at you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
avPlayerController.view.enableAutoLayoutConstraint()
avPlayerController.view.setCenterXConstraint(.equal, constantValue: 0)
avPlayerController.view.setCenterYConstraint(.equal, constantValue: 0)

extension UIView
{
    //Method to making translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints false.
    func enableAutoLayoutConstraint()
    {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    //Method to set Center-X Consttraint
    func setCenterXConstraint(_ relationType:NSLayoutRelation , constantValue:CGFloat)->NSLayoutConstraint
    {
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute:.centerX, relatedBy: relationType, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: constantValue)
        self.superview?.addConstraint(constraint)
        return constraint
    }

    //Method to set Center-Y Consttraint
    func setCenterYConstraint(_ relationType:NSLayoutRelation , constantValue:CGFloat)->NSLayoutConstraint
    {
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute:.centerY, relatedBy: relationType, toItem: self.superview, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: constantValue)
        self.superview?.addConstraint(constraint)
        return constraint
    }

}
```