# Scrollview doesn't cover all width

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ScrollView` combined with a `PageControll` and it contains 5 images which I want them to scroll. My problem is that the `ScrollView` width even if it is 320 in simulator it doesn't show covering the all width.

[image]

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    images.append(UIImage(named: "one.jpg")!)
    images.append(UIImage(named: "two.jpg")!)
    images.append(UIImage(named: "three.jpg")!)
    images.append(UIImage(named: "four.jpg")!)
    images.append(UIImage(named: "five.jpg")!)

    for var i = 0; i < images.count; i++ {
        var frame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imageView.image = images[i]
        self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(images.count), scrollView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Comment: That is because iPhone 6 width is 375 and you didn't have any constraints of ScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the scroll view's width is the correct size, but the content-mode of the UIImageView is set incorrectly such that as a result of the image being displayed having a smaller size than the scroll view, it will not fill the whole of the image view as you wanted.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

// Swift

imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding constraints to your image in your interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Put Constraints:
Main.storyboard -> UIImageView (for each UIImageView) -> Editor -> Pin -> Select leading,top space, bottom and trailing space to superview.

Comment: The UIImageView is created programatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollView doesn't have constraints