# how to center an image under the status bar in swift?

Tags: xcode, image, swift, center

I just can't seem to find the right code for it.
I want to place an image 20 points under the status bar (this will be the Y) and center it (this would be the X of course).
I can easily do it with storyboard but i'm struggling to do it programatically.
supposed this is my code:

```
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "someImage.png")!
            var bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
            //Tried with self.view.frame.size.height but not working
            bgImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 20, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 64)

           //also tried this which not worked as well 
          //  bgImage.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.hight - 20)
            self.view.addSubview(bgImage)
```

I've search apple docs but it's so unclear, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: bgImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 64)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once `bgImage` has the correct size, then the general solution for this is

```
bgImage.frame.origin.y = 20.0 // 20 down from the top
bgImage.frame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width - bgImage.frame.size.width) / 2.0 // centered left to right.
```

Comment: Was just wondering, if I want the Y to be 20 points up from the bottom, how should i write the code? plus, where can i find docs about it?

Comment: `bgImage.frame.origin.y = (self.view.bounds.size.height - bgImage.frame.size.height) - 20.0`. When I get confused, I draw things out on a piece of paper, but read [View and Window Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) to get a base understanding.

Answer (score 2):

how about something like this:

```
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "someImage.png")
var new_view = UIView(image: image)
view.addSubview(new_view);

// This is the default setting but be explicit anyway...
new_view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)

new_view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin 
new_view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.height - 20, view.bounds.midY)
```

Which adds the new subview, sets a flexible left & right margin on it and then centers it just under the status bar.

The programmatic code for which I found [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically).

Comment: well I test it and it's worked. I might use it - thank you for the info.