# iOS Swift Mute-unmute audio like facebook autoplay videos

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am currently using MPMoviePlayerController? to play video inside my app. But I want to have facebook style videos where initially the video plays mute but when the user taps it un-mutes.

I am new in programming, but as per my research I wasn't able to find anything in MPMoviePlayerController? in which we can do that.

Currently I am using the following code to play a video.

```
class InformationViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var thumbnailImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var videoPlayerView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var controlBtn: UIButton!

var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")!
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


@IBAction func controlBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    controlBtn.alpha = 0
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    let frameWidth = self.videoPlayerView.frame.size.width
    let frameHeight = self.videoPlayerView.frame.size.height

    //moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 24, y: 18, width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight)

    self.videoPlayerView.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)


    //     Send button backword
    self.videoPlayerView.sendSubviewToBack(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = false
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded

    // Pure Visual Format Language style (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically)
    (moviePlayer.view).setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    let views = ["view": videoPlayerView, "videoView": moviePlayer.view]

    var constH = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view]-(<=0)-[videoView(\(frameWidth))]", options: .AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    view.addConstraints(constH)
    var constW = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view]-(<=0)-[videoView(\(frameHeight))]", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
    view.addConstraints(constW)

}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)  ///< Don't for get this BTW!

    if let player = self.moviePlayer {
        player.stop()
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to an Apple technician it turns out that it's not possible to control or mute the audio using MPMoviePlayerController.

So , you can use AVFoundations AVPlayer class to mute video while playing like FB.

Source Code :

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

//Using this you can mute the audio and play only video as you wish
   avPlayer.muted = YES;

AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
avPlayerLayer.frame = IS_IPAD ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 748, 423): CGRectMake(0, 0, 311, 200);
avPlayerLayer.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
avPlayerLayer.videoGravity =AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
```

Once you muted the audio u can just change the boolean to unmute the audio like below .
  avPlayer.muted=NO;

Comment: As of iOS 9, it should be `AVPlayer.isMuted`, not `.muted`.