# Add "Vertical Spacing" programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have an `UIImageView` that I've added programmatically and a button which has been added in a Storyboard. And now I need to add "Vertical Spacing" between them, but I don't know how to do it. Would be easy if I would have added `UIImageView` in storyboard:

[image]

How can i solve the problem ?

Comment: you must also add constraints programmatically
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let suppose your `UIImageView` is added in the top as you put in your image above, then you can add constraints programmatically like in the following way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // assuming here you have added the self.imageView to the main view and it was declared before. 
    self.imageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

   // create the constraints with the constant value you want.
   var verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.imageView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.button, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)

  // activate the constraints
  NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([verticalSpace])
}
```

In the above code I only put the vertical space constraints, you need to set the necessary constraints to avoid warnings about it.

There are several ways of adding constraint programmatically you can read more in this very nice answer [SWIFT | Adding constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically).

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but now I get an error: "Unable to activate constraint with items <UIImageView...". Probably i did something wrong, gonna test it tomorrow again.

Comment: why isn't it `attribute: .Top`?

Comment: @user245954 Because it the `UIImageView` respect to the `UIButton` in the above case, if you want to change it , then you need to switch the roles.

Answer (score 5):

To add a vertical spacing between 2 views programmatically, you can use the following **Swift 3** code.

**view2** is the top view while **view1** of the bottom view.

```
let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view2, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([verticalSpace])
```

*Note: You must add the horizontal position for this to work.*

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at the [visual format language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1), and then take a look at the docs on how to programmatically create constraints [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html). Basically would look something like this

```
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary =
    NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.imageView, self.button);
    NSArray *constraints =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[imageView]-10-[button]"
                                            options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```