# How to set AutoLayouts for UICollectionView and Collectionview cell Programatically?

Tags: ios7

i am using collection view in my project which was taken programmatically,it's working fine with iphone 5 but to support for later versions of iphone (iphone6,6+) i am getting trouble .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the trouble/issue that you are facing ?

Comment: i tried with some methods which got through this website but collection view is still in same size it not getting changed according to simulator size i.e iphone 6 and 6+

Answer (score 0):

You might have added the collection view with a specific frame compatible for iPhone 5. In my opinion it is easy to do this directly on the xib/ storyboard directly, else you can add constraints programmatically as well.

Check this link

[Swift | Adding constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically)

Comment: But to do this i have some other components in viewdidload and in some places i have my collection view in API s responce please suggest me in objective c related code