# Add a view from a xib file to a UITableViewCell adding constraints

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints, xib

I created a xib file with a custom view that I want to display in a `UITableViewCell`.

The problem is: in the xib file, I set the width of the `UIView` to 600 (the `size` is `Freeform`) but I want to use constraints in order to obtain the correct width for every device.

I add this view in a `UITableViewCell` with `addSubview()` so I think that this view must be constraint to the view of the cell, is that right? How can I do this?

I add some code:

This my custom `UIView` related to the xib file:

```
class DownloadView: UIView, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate{

///utilizzata per mostrare il nome del file in download
@IBOutlet var nomeFileInDownloadLabel: UILabel!

///utilizzata per mostrare la percentuale di download completato
@IBOutlet var quantitaScaricataLabel: UILabel!

///utilizzata per mostrare il download
@IBOutlet var progressView: UIProgressView!

var view : UIView!

private var downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask?

//Initialization
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}


//I setup the xib from here
func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()

    //if I set the following one the view is a square
    //view.frame = bounds

    // Make the view stretch with containing view
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(view)
}

//I load the xib file
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "View", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}
//some code for other task 
...
}
```

In my `UITableView` in the method `tableView(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath)` I add the view:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DownloadRootTVC_IDcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DownloadTVCell

    //I get my custom view from an array
    let myView = self.listOfViewsDownlaod[indexPath.row]

    //I add the view to the cell
    cell.addSubview(myView)


    return cell
}
```

In this last method I think that I have to setup the constraint in order to fit my custom view in the `UITableViewCell` adapting it to the device width.

**EDIT:**

Since I want to adapt the width and the height of the subview to the cell I wrote this:

```
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
    cell.addConstraint(topConstraint)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
    cell.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)

    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    cell.addConstraint(leftConstraint)

    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
    cell.addConstraint(rightConstraint)
```

The only one that doesn't work is the right one, the view continue over the screen. I also tried to use `NSLayoutAttribute.Right` or `NSLayoutAttribute.RighMargin` or to set the constant to a negative value, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the issue:

the problem is in the `xibSetup()` method because I load the xib but I don't set the constraints! So my new method is:

```
func xibSetup() {
    let myView = loadViewFromNib()

    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(myView)

    let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myView.superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(leading)

    let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myView.superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(bottom)

    let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myView.superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(trailing)

    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myView.superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(top)

}
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your xib view doesn't have any constraints to it's superview when you add it as subview. You should create them programmatically. [There is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181982/5247504) a great example. For instance, if you want place your view in center of superview and same size you can write next:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
  let myView = UIView()
  myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
  myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  cell.addSubview(myView)
  let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
  cell.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

  let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
  cell.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

  let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
  cell.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

  let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
  cell.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
  return cell
}
```

It will looks like this (blue - tableView, red - myView):

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for yuor help guy. Unfortunately with this constraints the app crash, I'm going to learn how to use them in order to use them properly. Thanks

Comment: @Ernesto, ok, maybe you can show your error and I'll try to help?

Comment: I get this error:

 `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Unknown layout attribute' `
What do you think? Thanks you very much!!

Comment: @Ernesto, yeah, sorry. My fault. NSLayoutAttribute for width and height constraints shouldn't be .NotAnAttribute. I update my answer.

Comment: ok thanks! I'll try the new code this evening. I'll let you know about it

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but it doesn't work.. please see my edit in the post! Thanks

Comment: @Ernesto I also don't know. I update answer with tested example and screenshot. If it doesn't help please post actual code from cellForRow function.

Comment: your code works well in a new project. So I think the problem may occur while loading the nib, what do you think about the method "xibSetup()" (you can see it in the question)? Maybe I have to set up constraints also to that view..

Comment: finally I find the solution! See answer below! Thanks you!!