# How to change all TextField border colour in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uitextfield

How can I change all TextField border colour in Swift 3?
I've built one iPad application with many TextFields in my .xib file and now I want to change border colour, but it seems like so many lines to write a particular textfield

Comment: you can make extension of textfield.

Comment: use this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782693/properly-subclassing-uitextfield-in-swift

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this extension to create border for all textfields in your project.

```
extension UITextField
{
    open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set color #999999

Comment: Use this extension http://stackoverflow.com/a/42573932/7250862 and replace this `self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.uicolorFromHex(999999, alpha: 1)).cgColor`

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UITextField {
func cornerRadius(value: CGFloat) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = value
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
}}
```

Comment: call above method like: txtfield.cornerRadius(value: 5.0)

Comment: i want to change every TextField borderColor in my application more than 5000+ TextField

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new class which is subclass of UITextField as this :

```
import UIKit

class YourTextField: UITextField {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.setBorderColor()
    }
    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setBorderColor()
    }
    func setBorderColor(){
        self.layer.borderColor = .red // color you want
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3
        // code which is common for all text fields
    }
}
```

Now open xib select all text fields.
In identity inspector, change the custom class to `YourTextField`
This way even you have 1000 text fields in you project, no need to write even one more line for this purpose.