# "globally" manage app UI style (button, text field, etc) Obj-c

Tags: objective-c

I am new into objective c. In current project, I always outlet each button, text field to respective Controller, and then style it.

Is there any same approach like CSS in globally set the UI's properties/style?

For example, in CSS we can do like following code

```
.button_global_1{
    border-radius: 8px;
}

//in html
<button class="button_global_1"></button>
<button class="button_global_1"></button>
//2 buttons implements the same style. saving time.
```

Is there any such approach we can use in objective c? By outletting each UI components to each controller and then style it really consumes lots of time. And I started to find what is the best implementation to manage the UI's components.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044518/how-to-change-all-textfield-border-colour-in-swift-3/43044790

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes close to what you describe is the `UIAppearance` protocol. It doesn't support your example but you can do other stuff like:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can also create a UIButton subclass create a property for the corner radius and mark it with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`. That way it is accessible through the `UIAppearance` protocol.