# view.frame.origin.y does not affect subviews

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to move a `UITextField` up when the soft keyboard opens.

When I call `view.frame.origin.y = -150` from the `UIViewController`, the `UIView` is moved but the `UITextField` inside it is not. (The `UITextField` "jumps" and animates back to its original position.)

It was working some time ago and I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: You need to declare some layout constraints using NSAutoLayout to do something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: Right way to handle keyboard open and close : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: @EricD. Not a duplicate. I followed that solution but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

I had a constraint `mytextfield.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom`, when it should be `mytextfield.Top = SuperView.Bottom`

Answer (score 0):

I think [LucaD is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874809/view-frame-origin-y-does-not-affect-subviews#comment57487562_34874809) - you're missing constraints between your UITextField and UIViewController.

If you are using Interface Builder, see Apple's [Adding Layout Constraints by Control-Dragging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/add_constraints-control_drag.html)

Otherwise, if you are creating the UITextField programmatically, see [SWIFT | Adding constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically)

Comment: I have a `mytextfield.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom` constraint. Is that enough?

Comment: Are you sure the base UIView for the ViewController is being moved with the keyboard? @tumber033