# If I want to create these constraints programatically, how do I do so?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

I have a UITableView with those constraints. I'm trying to create the UITableView programmatically, but still want these constraints in code.

Comment: See section on `NSLayoutConstraints` here --> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this relatively easy by using visual format language:

Add your view, `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` to a dictionary. I used `views`. You also have to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for the constraints to work.

Example:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[yourView]-(-15)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[topLayout][yourView][botLayout]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do is :

```
let newView = UIView()
newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(newView)


  let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
 view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

  let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -15)
 view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

   let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
   view.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

   let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
  view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

for more info you can follow this [Swift | Adding constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically)