# How to set auto layout for UICollectionView programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I tried to create a `UICollectionView` with one of the following methods:

```
// method 1
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 3000), collectionViewLayout: layout)  

// method2
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)  

// method 3
collectionView = UICollectionView()
```

And then set auto layout constraints for it as below:

```
mainView.addSubView(collectionView)
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(mainView.leadingAnchor).active = true
collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(mainView.trailingAnchor).active = true
collectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(mainView.topAnchor, constant: 50).active = true
collectionView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(300).active = true
```

With method 1, the `UICollectionView` still shows by following the initial frame setup (0, 0, 500, 3000)

With method 2, the `UICollectionView` does not show up.

With method 3, it will crash with reason: "UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter"

What's the correct way to set auto layout constraints for this `UiCollectionView`?

Comment: Hope so this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/26181982/2594560

Comment: I have been using auto layouts in many places and they are all good. Just for `UICollectionView`, I don't know how to do it. Your link does not help, thanks.