# Programmatically adding UITableView leaves large space to the left of the cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I am adding a `UITableView` to a `UIViewController` programmatically and I am getting the following result:

[image]

I make the table in `viewDidLoad` like so:

```
    let size = view.bounds.size
    table = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 65, size.width, size.height-65), style: .Plain)
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    table.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    table.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

This is how I setup the `cells`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.imageView?.image = blueCheck
    cell.textLabel?.text = "TEXT"
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    return cell
}
```

I have also tried doing this which is a suggested answer to similar questions.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

I have also tried doing stuff like not using reusable `cells` and setting the `cell` frame but nothing works.

Any help or ideas is welcome. Thanks!

EDIT:

Setting `table.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero` is what is causing the empty `cells` to move to the left like in the SS shown above. When that is removed the empty `cells` have the large space as well.

I have also attempted using constraints programmatically to see if that made any difference. I got the same result sadly enough. This is what I tried:

```
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: table, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: table, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 65)
    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: table, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: table, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

Comment: Have you added any constraints? Checkout this answer on adding constraints programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically

Comment: Just tried that and the result is the same. :(

Comment: Any output in the console about conflicting constraints, etc? Can you edit your post and add the constraints you added?

Comment: No conflicting constraints. Added the constraints to the post.

Comment: Did you actually add constraints to your view after initializing them?

Comment: Yes, and I added the line `table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue was an iOS 9 thing where sometimes you also need to set`cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false` in order to customize insets and margins. I haven't run into this when using the story board + constraints so I am not sure if this only something that comes up when making everything programmatically.

Here is the code I added to make it work:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        table.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    table.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    table.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Superview's Frame before adding this Tableview as subview.