# AutoLayout resize custom UIView content

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, ios-autolayout

I have a standard UIView added via IB which changes size based on orientation using constraints. Programatically I add a custom component (sub-classing UIView) to this view which by default is the sam size as its parent view. Problem is, how do I get my custom view (programatically added) to update its size based to match its parent when the parents size changes (due to orientation change)?

```
@IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let frame = cardView.bounds
    // Custom component sub classes UI View
    // Should always be same size as its parent
    let imageTemplateView: ImageTemplateView = ImageTemplateView(frame: frame)

    cardView.addSubview(imageTemplateView)
}
```

Comment: try using `clipsToBounds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes `viewDidLayoutSubviews`to resolve our issue,

**Description:**

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method.

Instead of `viewDidLoad` use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`as follows

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let imageTemplateView: ImageTemplateView = ImageTemplateView(frame: frame)
    cardView.addSubview(imageTemplateView)
    imageTemplateView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

**UPDATE:**

- Declare variable above `viewdidload`

  ```
  var imageTemplateView: ImageTemplateView = ImageTemplateView()
  ```
- set frame and add it as sub view in viewdidload

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    imageTemplateView = ImageTemplateView(frame: frame)
    cardView.addSubview(imageTemplateView)
    imageTemplateView.clipsToBounds = true
  }
  ```
- In `viewDidLayoutSubviews` just set the frame alone,so that whenever orientation changes `ImageTemplateView`'s frame will be updated

  ```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    imageTemplateView = ImageTemplateView(frame: frame)
  }
  ```

Comment: it will keep adds one more imageTemplateView as subview when ever viewDidLayoutSubviews called

Comment: This is wrong approach. adding any object like imageview or label or else in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`  is bad idea because everytime it will add new object when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` get called. If your device's orientation change then also this method will be called. So add view in `viewdidload` and resize it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` according to need.

Comment: raki  already suggested this.check update..Only changing the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1):

Set your programmatically added view's `top,bottom,leading and trailing` constraints with constant `0` of each. So, it will always keep same size with respect to parent view that you have added in `IB`. If you want rational(like half height and width of parent view or anything else) `height` or `width` then you can manage it by playing with `constant` and `multiplier`.

If you don't have idea that how to add constraints programmatically then you can refer [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically).

Comment: I think using viewDidLayoutSubviews is simplest in this instance, but I can see how setting the constraints programatically is beneficial for greater positioning accuracy - Many Thanks

Comment: you're welcome..!!! adding new objects in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not good approach. You should add it from `viewdidload` which is get called only once.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
var imageTemplateView:ImageTemplateView!

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageTemplateView = ImageTemplateView(frame: cardView.bounds)
    cardView.addSubview(imageTemplateView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    imageTemplateView.frame = cardView.bounds
}
```

Comment: modified viewDidLayoutSubviews method

Answer (score 0):

You can use Size Class feature. Set constraint and add view base or orientation change.
Check this Tutorial
http://www.hossamghareeb.com/size-classes-tutorial/

Comment: I'm using Size Classes on the UIView added via IB to alter its appearance based on orientation/device. Not sure how I would do that programatically on the custom view thats added - All this view needs to do is be the same size as its parent