# How to properly activate constraints in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to programmatically add a button view object to my scene for an iOS app written in swift. I am trying to follow the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263784

But I cannot see the button on the scene. I call this method from my viewDidLoad method.

```
    func buildLoginButton() -> UIButton
{
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: .Normal)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    let c1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let c2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(nil, constant: 200).active = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(nil, constant: 100).active = true

     NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([c1, c2])
    view.bringSubviewToFront(button)

    return button
}
```

Comment: Do you get any warnings regarding ambiguous layout constraints in debug pane?

Comment: Have you ensured `buildLoginButton()` gets called? On the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let button = UIButton()
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Stop! You forgot to say this:

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
```

You must say this on any view that you create, put into the interface, and try to apply constraints to.