# Swift - Xcode 8 - iOS 10 - Can't create simple constraint

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, autolayout

**EDIT - I fixed it.  See answer.**

I'm trying to learn how to create constraints programmatically. I tried to constrain a `UILabel` to the top of the screen, using this code, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //the variable label already exists. I make a UILabel.
    label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Hello"
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    //I add the label to the ViewController
    view.addSubview(label)

    //I use an array of constraints because I will make more later.
    let constraints : [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    ]
    view.addConstraints(constraints)
}
```

When I run my app, I get an error beginning with:

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

My intended equation for the constraint was:

**label.top = 1.0 * topLayoutGuide.bottom + 0.0**

When I created what seems to be an identical constraint with Interface Builder, it worked.  However, it doesn't when I try to do it programatically.  What's wrong with what I'm doing, and how can I programmatically make a constraint using `NSLayoutConstraint` that will pin my Label to the top of the screen right below the status bar?

**My sources:**

[Apple - Anatomy of a Constraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1)

[Apple - Programmatically creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH16-SW1)

[StackOverflow - SWIFT | Adding constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically)

Comment: Fwiw, if you're doing a lot of programmatic constrains, check out SnapKit or some other AutoLayout framework to make your life a million times easier.

Comment: @brandonscript I know, and I would rather use IB or something else, but I want to understand how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

This can be fixed by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to be false, to avoid clashes with existing Mask Constraints:

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```