# Positioning view in view

Tags: swift, uiview

I have couple questions about positioning and autoresizing views with code (without using visual Autolayout constrains tools)
[image: Positing and autoresizing views]

#### Question 1:

How to positioning center (X and Y) View 2 in View 1?

#### Question 2:

How to autoresize View 2 in View 1 and add View 3 (make it center align on View 2)?

---

P.S.: Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find your answer in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181982/5160019

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

For question #1:

You can calculate the x and y values from the superview's width and height. The subview will then be positioned like this:

```
subView.center = CGPoint(x: superView.frame.size.width/2, y: superView.frame.size.height/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method to position the views

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

   view1.center = self.view.center
   view2.center = self.view1.center
   view3.center = self.view2.center
}
```

Comment: variable names start with lowercase letters.