# Swift 3 iOS 10 - Constraints with Format

Tags: swift3, ios10

Trying to add constraints with format. However I keep getting stumped. Please help, previously this worked.

```
addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
```

How do resolve this for swift 3 and iOS 10. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically