# how to set constraints to tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have searched SO, but could not find any helpful answer.

I have a storyboard with three (3) textfields, to these textfields I want to make autocomplete textfields.

[image]

Am creating tableviews like this

```
let tblNumbers = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(16,140,74,200), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
var arrStrNo = [String]()
var arrStrNum = [String]()

let tblYears = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(120,140,74,200), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
var arrStrYr = [String]()
var arrStrYears = [String]()

let tblType = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(222,140,74,200), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
var arrStrTyp = [String]()
var arrStrType = [String]()
```

So programmatically am showing tableviews to just below textfields in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

```
table.reloadData()
```

In storyboard am setting constraints to textfields, now am wondering how can I set constraints to these tableviews, so it should be exactly below the textfields in all size screens.

[image]

Programmitically, am trying like below to set constraints to tableviews in `viewDidLoad` method but its not working

```
func setConstraintsToYearTableView(){

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tblYears, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 190)
        let leadingContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tblYears, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 120)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tblYears, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tblYears, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([topConstraint, leadingContraint, trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint])

}
```

Comment: Use only single tableView, and change dataSource according to your need.
Pin tableView in storyboard it self.

Comment: but i want to have tableview under three textfields, my question is "how to set constraints to tableview programmatically" ?

Comment: Yes you can pin tableView's top from textField's bottom then update that constraint to negative value, so tableView will go under textField.

Comment: Am new to iOS,swift, can you provide any sample code. i will be very thankfull for that

Comment: You can check sample code from here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26181982/5580393  i hope it will help

Comment: yeah tried that. but could not achieve required functionality

Comment: place only single tableview in storyboard and don't assign any constraint, now when user click on text field set tableview frame programmatically bellow the textfiled according to  textfield's frame.