# swift 8 iOS data is getting crop in scrollview while adding dynamically data

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uiview, scrollview

[image]

[image]

Hi I am developing small IOS application in which I am using scrollview with auto-layout.Inside scroll I am adding two more views. I am using IB and auto-layout constraints. I am adding two views in side one after another in vertical manner. I have added outer constraints like trailing, leading, top, bottom space. I also added height constraints for both views. Till this everything is working fine.

But my passengerView has some dynamic content. For that reason I want to make height constraint greater than equal to instead of equal to.

my code is:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var passengerView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var detailView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.name.frame.height * CGFloat(index) + CGFloat(49)), width: 161, height: 32))
                                    let idLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 161, y: (self.name.frame.height * CGFloat(index) + CGFloat(49)), width: 161, height: 32))
                                   // nameLabel.text = dsdh?["name"] as? String
                                    nameLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
                                    nameLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                                    nameLabel.textAlignment = .center;
                                    self.passengerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
                                    //idLabel.text = dsdh?["document_Type"] as? String
                                    idLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
                                    idLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                                    idLabel.textAlignment = .center;
                                    self.passengerView.addSubview(idLabel)
                                    self.secondView.addSubview(self.passengerView)
                                    self.detailView.frame = CGRect(x: self.detailView.frame.origin.x, y: self.detailView.frame.origin.y + CGFloat(32) , width: self.detailView.frame.size.width, height: self.detailView.frame.size.height)
                                      self.secondView.addSubview(self.detailView)
                                    //self.scrollView.addSubview(self.detailView)
                                    self.secondView.frame = CGRect(x: self.secondView.frame.origin.x, y: self.secondView.frame.origin.y , width: self.secondView.frame.size.width, height: self.secondView.frame.size.height + CGFloat(5))

                                    self.scrollView.addSubview(self.secondView)
                                    //self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width , height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height + CGFloat(32))
                                    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: self.scrollView.frame.origin.x, y: self.scrollView.frame.origin.y , width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height + CGFloat(0))
                                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y , width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height + CGFloat(0))

}
```

Comment: Show us a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Looking at your image, it appears that the screen can be easily made using a tableview and add the cells dynamically based on contents required.

Comment: Please Anybody provider me solution for that.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be as following:

1. Implement a `UIScrollView` that is constraint to the `Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom` constraints of your main view.
2. Add a `UIView` to the `UIScrollView` and constrain it to the `Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom` of your `UIScrollView`. Important is to also constrain this `UIView's` width to your **main view, not your scroll view!** In this way this `UIView` will serve you as a `Content View` for the `UIScrollView`. **This step is mandatory if you are doing this in Interface Builder!**
3. Add a `UIStackView` to your `Content View` (the view from the previous step) and constrain it to the `Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom` of the `Content View`.
4. Add all your `UILabels`, your `Detail View`, `QR Code View` and `Passenger View` as children to this `UIStackView`.
5. Since you want only your `Passenger View` to have a dynamic height you can set your `UIStackView's` axis to `Vertical` and `Content Mode` to `Fill`. Then you will provide a height for all of the children of the `UIStackView` **except the `Passenger View`**.

In this way the `Content Size` of your `UIScrollView` will adapt based on the height of the `UIStackView` and the height of the `UIStackView` willl adapt based on the needed height for the `Passenger View`.

Comment: Hi Stefan,  i tried with this. when i am adding the label into passengerView its going to beyond that and some of adding into below view. If you want me to share the code with you please send me mail-id.