# How to add constraint with dynamic width programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm new to iOS development. I want to build layout without storyboard or xib/nib. So I am trying to add constraints programmatically.
I have searched some tutorials about add constraints programmatically. But the view can't show correctly.

I'm trying this code in my ViewController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let testView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(testView)

    // Add Constraints
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal
        , toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)
    let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal
        , toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -50.0)
    let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 50.0)
    let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -50.0)
    self.view.addConstraints([top, bottom, leading, trailing])
}
```

Generally, they don't need to define the size of view or constraints about width and height in tutorials. But the views can be shown on their tutorial. In my case, my **testView** can't show it in the app even top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints have been set. Am I missed something? What's the problem?

one of the tutorials:
http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nslayoutconstraint-programatically-sample-code/

Edit:
Let's me explain more. I want to create a `UIView` that suitable for universal device. The `UIView` has top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints with `constant: 10`. So, I don't need to set size of `UIView`.

[Expected Result (I am using draw tool to simulate the result)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxXMo.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you checked all the similiar questions already before asking? Like this for example that have massive answers and explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically

Comment: I had checked this question before. The size of `UIView` had been defined to width: 100, height: 100 in the highest rate answer. I have updated my question. Please check, thanks.

Comment: try adding view.layoutIfNeeded after adding the constraints if none of the other solutions work for you or the multiple answers here.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a view constraint to the bottom of the screen with height equal to 80:

```
var yourView = UIView()
yourView.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
yourSuperView.addSubview(yourView)

// Pin the leading edge of yourView  to the leading edge of the main view
yourView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor).active = true

// Pin the trailing edge of yourView to the leading trailing edge
yourView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor).active = true

// Pin the bottomedge of yourView to the margin's leading edge
yourView .bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true

// The height of your view
yourView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(80).active = true
```

Comment: Avoid posting exact copies of your answer to multiple questions. You can post a comment and link to your answer if you feel that the question is a duplicate you can also flag it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. Do not set `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.  You only need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` for the subview you are adding.
2. You are using `.greaterThanOrEqual` constraints instead of `.equal` constraints.  The problem with that is that leaves a lot of wiggle room and you are getting values that cause your `testView` to have `0` width.  If you change to `.equal` that will properly constrain the values.

Comment: `testView` still not show on my screen after I removed `self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and changed `.greaterThanOrEqual` to `.equal`

Comment: Append your updated code to the question, but don't remove the original code.  Did you change both .greaterThanOrEquals to .equal ?