# How to use UIView in UIViewController ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, cardview

I make UIView like this. but I want to use this in UIViewController
What should I do?

import UIKit

```
class CardView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 3
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor.black
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add it in your viewController you have several options:

1. *Add it directly in storyboard (best option):*

drag a view in viewController via inspector/object library on the bottom right side in xCode

[UIView object screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBCRs.png)

add constraints, then tap on the view in

[Constraints screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aesfm.png)

and pick your custom class in identity inspector/custom class field

2. *You can also use a view loaded from xib*
   Google different way to load from xib.
3. *You can add it in code. It's a little bit harder:*

Create a lazy property:

```
lazy var cardView: CardView = {
        let cardView = CardView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))
        cardView.backgroundColor = .gray
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
        return cardView
    }()
```

Add custom view in viewDidLoad for example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /* Adding subview to the VC */
    view.addSubview(cardView)
}
```

Then add constraints. You can center it vertically/horizontally and then set custom height/width. It depends on what you want...

Check this out:
[Swift | Adding constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically)

I advise you to read Apple's documentation rather then just copy pasting code.
Should definitely read "documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html" if you still haven't.

Comment: Thanks bro. 
Your answer was a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new uiview to your storyboard or xib file and set its class as CardView as shown [image]

Comment: I did like you. but I don't know What should I use cardview in textview