# Autolayout not working for my nib when added subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've created an xib and loaded the nib in my `viewDidLayOutSubviews`:

I then added the subview:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if (myCustomView == nil) {

        myCustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Help", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? HelpView
        self.view.addSubview(myCustomView!)
    }
}
```

My constraints are all set up correctly in my xib (toggling between devices look okay), however when I launch the app on a different device the autolayout is not updated. How do I fix this? Thank you!

Edit:

Toggled for iPhone 7, but launching for iPhone 7 Plus
[image]

Toggled for iPhone 7 Plus, launching for iPhone 7 Plus
[image]

Comment: Try to implement it in viewDidApprear

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your xib and the device on which layouts are break.

Comment: @GirishM hmm... that doesn't work.. I'm 100% sure my constraints are set up correctly. However I do realise that toggling the right device for the xib and launching to the same device works okay, but this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Also, you have two xibs here.

Comment: @ankit I added screenshots

Comment: where exactly is the issue, is it "Tap the X.."

Comment: @ankit the trailing space is not sticked towards the right side which is causing the space. In iPad the space is even larger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142564/discussion-between-ankit-and-iamhx).

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints may be setup correctly in your nib, but you don't have any constraints when you call self.view.addSubview(myCustomView!), so the frame is just going to be whatever it is in the nib file.  You need to constraint myCustomView to self.view.  Give it equal width, center X, equal top and a fixed height (or use the intrinsic height) and it should be fine.  Make sure you turn off translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.

Comment: I've never added constraints programmatically, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Use NSLayoutAnchor and set the constraints as outlined above.  I have an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically/40184218#40184218

Answer (score 0):

just add this line below

**self.view.addSubview(myCustomView!)**

```
myCustomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
//Views to add constraints to
let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("myCustomView",myCustomView))

//Horizontal constraints
let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[myCustomView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)

//Vertical constraints
let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[myCustomView(SpecifyFixedHeight)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
```