# Load image auto resize

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Can iOS set scale before load image?

Just like Android "Glide", auto resize image to fit layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, you can set an image to scale to fit the view before it's loaded. You do this by setting by setting *constraints* on the view that will be displaying the image, typically a `UIImageView`.

You can set the constraints in Interface Builder, or refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181982/149097) for ways to do it programmatically in your code.

Comment: oh! i found it in interface builder, thx very much