# child view not visible after applying auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, xib, uistackview

I have a xib that defines a view which is a single grey rectangle. The view is added programmatically to a UIStackView, which is inside a UIScrollView. The added views show up fine until I try adding any constraint to the grey rectangle, then they all disappear. 
I'm not experienced with how constraints work however ANY constraint I try to add causes the grey rectangles to disappear.
I'm abit new to iOS development so any pointers in the right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its just the way you are setting the constraints (maybe you could post your code?). I prefer to set the constraints with the interface builder, since I'm new to iOS development. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically) might help you.

> Do you plan to have a squared `UIView` of *width: 100* and *Height:
>   100* centered inside the `UIView` of an `UIViewController`? If so, you
>   may try one of the 7 following Swift 3 Auto Layout snippets:
>
> ---
>
> #### 1. `NSLayoutConstraint` + `addConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` style
>
> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>
>     let newView = UIView()
>     newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
>     newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>     view.addSubview(newView)
>
>     let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy:
> ```
>
> NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
>           let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy:
>   NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
>           let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
>   toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier:
>   1, constant: 100)
>           let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy:
>   NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
>
> ```
>     view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> #### 2. `NSLayoutConstraint` + `activate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` style Note: `activate(_ constraints:
>
> [NSLayoutConstraint])` requires iOS 8
>
> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>
>     let newView = UIView()
>     newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
>     newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>     view.addSubview(newView)
>
>     let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy:
> ```
>
> NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
>           let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy:
>   NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
>           let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
>   toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier:
>   1, constant: 100)
>           let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy:
>   NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
>
> ```
>     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> #### 3. Pure Visual Format Language style + `addConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` style
>
> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>
>     let newView = UIView()
>     newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
>     newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>     view.addSubview(newView)
>
>     let views = ["view": view, "newView": newView]
>     let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat:
> ```
>
> "H:[view]-(<=0)-[newView(100)]", options:
>   NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
>           let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat:
>   "V:[view]-(<=0)-[newView(100)]", options:
>   NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)
>
> ```
>     view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
>     view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> #### 4. `NSLayoutConstraint` + Visual Format Language + `activate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` style Note: `activate(_
>
> constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` requires iOS 8
>
> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>
>     let newView = UIView()
>     newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
>     newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>     view.addSubview(newView)
>
>     let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy:
> ```
>
> NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
>           let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy:
>   NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute:
>   NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
>
> ```
>     let views = ["newView": newView]
>     let widthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[newView(100)]",
> ```
>
> options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views:
>   views)
>           let heightConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[newView(100)]",
>   options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views:
>   views)
>
> ```
>     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
>     NSLayoutConstraint.activate(widthConstraints)
>     NSLayoutConstraint.activate(heightConstraints)
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> #### 5. `UIViewAutoresizing` style Note: Springs and Struts will be translated into corresponding auto layout constraints at runtime.
>
> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>
>     let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
>     newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
>     newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
>     view.addSubview(newView)
>
>     newView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
>     newView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleLeftMargin,
> ```
>
> UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleRightMargin,
>   UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleTopMargin,
>   UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleBottomMargin]
>       }
>
> ---
>
> #### 6. `NSLayoutAnchor` + `activate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` style Note: `activate(_ constraints:
>
> [NSLayoutConstraint])`requires iOS 8,`NSLayoutAnchor` requires iOS 9
>
> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>
>     let newView = UIView()
>     newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
>     newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>     view.addSubview(newView)
>
>     let horizontalConstraint = newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
>     let verticalConstraint = newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
>     let widthConstraint = newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
>     let heightConstraint = newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
>     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> #### 7. Subclassing + `activate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` style Note: `activate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])` requires
>
> iOS 8, `NSLayoutAnchor` requires iOS 9
>
> ```
> import UIKit
>
> class CustomView: UIView {
>
>     override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
>         return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
>     }
>
> }
>
> class ViewController: UIViewController {
>
>     override func viewDidLoad() {
>         super.viewDidLoad()
>
>         let newView = CustomView()
>         newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
>         newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>         view.addSubview(newView)
>
>         let horizontalConstraint = newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
>         let verticalConstraint = newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
>         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Also, [check the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)