# How to make a scroll view programmatically in Xcode and add view in it?

Tags: uiscrollview, swift4, xcode9, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to make a scroll view programmatically in xcode and want to add anchor constraints using safe area layout guide  Auto Layout. And want to add some text views button and map init but could not find any proper way to do this. I have tried many codes. What is the proper code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for programmatically create `Scroll view` and add `UIView` inside XCode

#### Swift 4.0

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    let myView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        // add the scroll view to self.view
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // constrain the scroll view to 8-pts on each side
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        
        //Frame for UIView here
        myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        scrollView.addSubview(myView)
    }

}
```

Comment: It depends on contents inside `UIView`. You have to add something inside view or increase view height. @AnilPervaiz

Comment: you have to give proper frame and use auto layout programmatically. @AnilPervaiz

Comment: @AnilPervaiz please check this link for autolayout - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181982/4803556

Comment: Yes i am having a problem with the auto layout , i put a sub view into my view  it works but   when i put more views in it  it do not shows up.