# View is showing only in status bar in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am developing **hybrid** app using `WKWebView` everything is working fine in all size simulators but when i am running code in iPhone the progress bar is showing on the screen all the time and the view is appear in **status bar** ,also when I scroll the screen in status bar I can see the scrolling of contents of my app.

```
var webview:WKWebView!
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
wkwebview = WKWebView(frame:self.view.frame,configuration:configuration)
self.view = wkwebview
wkwebview.load(req as URLRequest)
```

Can anyone knows what is this ?? I am using Xcode 9.2 and macOS Sierra version 
 10.12.6

**Edited :**

If I stops **Internet** it shows view in the iphone(fine).
  **It is also working fine in iphone 6 and above**.

[image: Here is Image]

Comment: What method are you executing this code in?

Comment: show screenshot ..

Comment: Why dont you share a screen shot

Comment: I added screenshot @AbhishekMitra,Jitendra

Comment: @jakirhussain i have seen below, there is 2 comments with answer, and it seems to work perfectly, by using any of these code. If you have tried both and though you didn't rectify the issue, then you have to show your storyboard along with your class code. Thanks

Comment: @jakirhussain . try  `let wkwebview = WKWebView(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds,configuration:configuration)` it should work

Comment: Is it working fine on iOS 6 and above or iPhone 6 and above?

Comment: I think you need to check 2 things. First, check if any other view don't cover your web view (view with spinner can cover your webview). Then try to add constraints to your web view as @biloshkurskyi.ss suggested. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was **Internet** issue. I was using LAN for running this App and the IP was conflicting, so when I update the IP of my iPhone the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more flexible with constraints: [check full descriptions with examples how to work with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically).

One of possible way for you is to use `NSLayoutConstraint` + `Visual Format Language`:

```
    let webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    webview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(webview)
    webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!))

    let views = ["webview": webview]
    let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[webview]-|", options: .alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views)
    let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[webview]-|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: views)

    self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
    self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
```

Comment: @jakirhussain what result you get?

Comment: After using your code I can't see the view in status bar

Comment: @jakirhussain try to inspect your view hierarchy in the inspector. Maybe your parent view has incorrect frame too.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let webView = WKWebView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com/")!))

}
```

check this screenshot --- https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVAFW.png

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like something is above your webview. Have you debugged your view hierarchy already ?

Comment: It is working fine is simulator as well as ios 6 and above so I don't thing that there is any view hierarchy issue@Milander

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
Put this code in `viewWillApear`

```
var screenViewBounds: CGRect? = wkWebView?.bounds
    screenViewBounds?.origin.y = 20
    screenViewBounds?.size.height = screenViewBounds?.size.height - 20
    wkWebView?.frame = screenViewBounds
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Jakir Hussain the solution to this question is simple.
You need to go to the "General" tab and then go to "Status Bar" and select "Requires FUll Screen"