# AutoLayout not working for Plus models

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I am currently developing an educational app, the first view controller displays the main categories and the second one (almost like Pinterest) displays the several subcategories. The Auto layout that I used works perfectly for the iPhone 6, 7, 8 and X however the Plus models of those are a little bit distorted

This is how it looks in models 6, 7, 8 and X

[image]

[image]

However when I run it in the Plus models, it looks like the following:

[image]

[image]

I have the following Auto Layout Code

This Auto Layout corresponds to the first View Controller, I am using a Stack View so the ScrollView's height can adjust depending on the content of the stack view. 
[image]

This Auto Layout corresponds to the Pinterest-like sub categories view controller. I am using the code employed by Ryan Wenderlich, however instead of using images, in both view controllers i'm using buttons so the user can go to the corresponding section. I add them programatically but always connected to the cell item prototype.

How can I make it so the Auto layout works for the Plus models?
[image]

Comment: `S` Model you mean `Plus` models?

Comment: exactly, for example the iPhone 6S, 7S and 8S

Comment: What is your StackView type? Alignment and distribution?

Comment: StackView type = Vertical; Alignment = Fill and Distribution = Equal Spacing

Comment: It's hard to find the issue without see the code. could you upload your code? or share it with me and I can look your code and find the issue.

Comment: Sure, here is the link for my GitHub project:

Comment: https://github.com/francisc112/StockTraderII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your issue:

Every button have a title of `Button` and you should remove default title. that title pushed the button's image and because of title white color, you didn't see it.

You also can control image of `UIButton`s by `Control > Alignment section` look at the screen shot that I attached.

[image]

By the way, I recommend you to use `UIImageView` + `UIButton` over it instead of using `UIButton`'s image content.

*Edit*

`CollectionView` is a totally mess! It will be eat a lot of RAM. You have a lot of cells over each other.

[image]

by the way, seems like your second view controller issue related to the `stackviews` that is not set constraint.

```
    cell.addSubview(stackView)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

I just centered one of the `stackview`s and I founded out It's related to the constraint.

look at this like for setting `Constraint` programatically: 
[Swift | Adding constraints programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/swift-adding-constraints-programmatically?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped me so much! and what about the second view controller? where there is a scroll view with a collection view like Pinterest? When I use it in the iPhone 8S and 7S models, it also looks very distorted