# NSLayoutConstraints with visual format doesn't work as expected when in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift

I am putting a `UILabel` inside a `UIScrollView`, I'd like to add these constraints to the label:

1. Top margin is 20
2. Left margin is 20
3. Right margin is 20
4. Label's height is 40

Here's the code I wrote for these constraints using visual format:

```
let label = UILabel.init(frame: .zero)
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.text = "Some Text"
scrollView.addSubview(label)

let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[label]-20-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["label": label]
)

let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|-20-[label(40)]",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["label": label]
)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(horizontalConstraints + verticalConstraints)
```

But [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Dd2.png) is what I'm getting (can't upload photo because I have low reputations). I added borders to the views, the blue one is the border of `UIScrollView`, the red one is the border of the `UILabel`

Comment: Use `NSLayoutConstraint` is far better

Comment: Does the `scrollView` has its constraints already setup appropriately?

Comment: Also, is it required to deal with [FVL](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html)? I would assume that there are easier options, you might want to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/how-to-add-constraints-programmatically-using-swift

Comment: Thank you guys, I have posted an answer down there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't correct. Here is how your code should looks. And if you use this way of adding constraints, you don't need to activate constraints with special method. These vertical and horizontal constraints have already activated.

```
//horizontal constraints
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[v0]-20-|", 
options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": label]))

//vertical constraints
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-20-[v0(40)]", 
options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": label]))
```

Explanation of syntax:

`"H", "V"` - horizontal, vertical constraints

`"|"` - anchor, for example `"H:|[v0]"` - left anchor

`"-20-"` - offset, for example "V:|-20-[v0]" - top anchor with offset 20

`"[v0(40)]"` - this is the size of view, for example `"V:[v0(40)]"` - height is 40

`"[v0]"` -  your first view in visual format. This format can set constraints for several views.

For example:

(format: "V:|-16-[v0]-8-[v1(44)]-16-[v2(1)]|", views: ["v0": firstView], ["v1": secondView], ["v2": thirdView])

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. Although I do not know why this happens, whether it's a bug with `UIScrollView` or things just have to be done this way.

Apparently, when you add subviews to a `UIScrollView` in Story Board, you'll always get a warning saying that the position of the subviews are ambiguous. So, what you would do is to add a `UIView` to the scroll view and add these constraints to it:

1. Top = 0, Leading = 0, Trailing = 0 and Bottom = 0
2. `UIView` is centered both horizontally and vertically in the scroll view

After that, you're good to add subviews to `UIView` without getting those warnings.

Same reason applies here, when you want to add subviews to a `UIScrollView` programmatically, and also set up some constraints, you should put a `UIView` inside the scroll view and put all subviews inside the `UIView`:

```
let subviewContainer = UIView.init(frame: .zero)
subviewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scrollView.addSubview(subviewContainer)

var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

// Step 1, set up horizontal constraints to make leading & trailing = 0
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[subviewContainer]-0-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["subviewContainer": subviewContainer]
)

// Step 2, set up vertical constraints to make top & bottom = 0
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[subviewContainer]-0-|",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: ["subviewContainer": subviewContainer]
)

// **Step 3, center "subviewContainer" horizontally & vertically in scroll view**
constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: subviewContainer,
        attribute: .centerX,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: scrollView,
        attribute: .centerX,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

constraints.append(
    NSLayoutConstraint.init(
        item: subviewContainer,
        attribute: .centerY,
        relatedBy: .equal,
        toItem: scrollView,
        attribute: .centerY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0
    )
)

// Step 4, activate all constraints
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

After these 4 steps, you are now good to add subviews to "subviewContainer".