# set Webview in safe area of iphone X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I am new to `Xcode` and I don't know how to set `webview` in `safe area` of iPhone X. I have gone through couple of various answers, but they didn't help. The only thing I know about this app is, the view is set programmatically. Below is my `ViewController.swift` file.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate
{
    var webView       = WKWebView()
    var containerView = WKWebView() //Footer  Webview

    override func loadView()
    {
        super.loadView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let theConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        //Bind Swift and Javascript interface through MessageHandler IOSJSObject
        theConfiguration.userContentController.add(self, name: "IOSJSObject")

        /* Webview intialization Start */
        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-65), configuration: theConfiguration)

        containerView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-45, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 45), configuration: theConfiguration)
        /* Webview intialization End */


        /* Error Page Code Start */
        if(TestConnection.isConnectedToNetwork())
        {
            let url:URL = URL(string:"example.com")!

            let request :URLRequest = URLRequest(url:url)

            if let navController = self.navigationController
            {
                navController.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            webView.load(request)
        }
        else
        {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "error-connection", ofType: "html")
            let text = try? String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            webView.loadHTMLString(text!, baseURL: nil)
        }

        /* Error Page Code End */

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        /* Container View Border Code Start*/
        let myColor : UIColor  = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        self.containerView.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor;
        self.containerView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        /* Container View Border Code End*/

        /* Container View Button Home Back Refresh Code Start*/
        let home = UIImage(named: "nptl-home.png")
        let back = UIImage(named: "nptl-back.png")
        //let refresh = UIImage(named: "nptl-refresh.png")


        let homeButton = UIButton()
        let backButton = UIButton()
        //let refreshButton = UIButton()

        homeButton.setImage(home, for: UIControlState())
        homeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState())

        backButton.setImage(back, for: UIControlState())
        backButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState())

        //refreshButton.setImage(refresh, for: UIControlState())
        //refreshButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState())

        homeButton.frame = CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4)-50, y: 4, width: 37, height: 37)
        homeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.home(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        backButton.frame = CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/1.33)+13, y: 4, width: 31, height: 37)
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.goBack(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        //refreshButton.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width-60, y: 4, width: 48, height: 37)
        //refreshButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.doRefresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        containerView.addSubview(homeButton)
        containerView.addSubview(backButton)
        //containerView.addSubview(refreshButton)

        /* Container View Button Home Back Refresh Code End*/

        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        self.view.addSubview(containerView)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate  = self
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false   //No Bounce of Webview Screen From Top

        if(TestConnection.isConnectedToNetwork())
        {
            checkUpdate()
        }
    }


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!,withError error: Error)
    {
        viewDidLoad()
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)
    {
        if let messageBody:NSDictionary = message.body as? NSDictionary
        {
            print(" \(message.body)")

            let myActionName = messageBody["actionName"] as! String
            if myActionName == "shareApp"
            {
                let myShareAppSubject = messageBody["shareAppSubject"] as! String
                let myShareAppUrl = messageBody["shareAppURL"] as! String
                shareApp(myShareAppSubject,shareAppUrl:myShareAppUrl)
            }
            else if myActionName == "rateApp"
            {
                rateApp()
            }
            else if myActionName == "shareAppPage"
            {
                let myShareAppMessageSubject = messageBody["shareAppPageMessageSubject"] as! String
                let myShareAppMessageURL = messageBody["shareAppPageMessageURL"] as! String

                shareAppPage(myShareAppMessageSubject, shareAppPageURL: myShareAppMessageURL)
            }
            else if myActionName == "error"
            {
                viewDidLoad()
            }
            else if myActionName == "loadFromBaseUrl"
            {
                viewDidLoad()
            }
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    /* Stop the network activity indicator when the loading finishes */
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (@escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void))
    {
        if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tel"
        {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
        if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "mailto"
        {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(navigationAction.request.url!)
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Start Of Custom bottomfooter


    @objc func doRefresh(_: AnyObject)
    {
        print("Refresh");

        webView.reload()
    }

    @objc func goBack(_: AnyObject)
    {
        if webView.canGoBack
        {
            webView.goBack()
        }
    }
    @objc func home(_: AnyObject)
    {
        //viewDidLoad()
        if(TestConnection.isConnectedToNetwork())
        {
            let url:URL = URL(string:"example.com")!

            let request :URLRequest = URLRequest(url:url)

            if let navController = self.navigationController
            {
                navController.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            webView.load(request)

        }
        else
        {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "error-connection", ofType: "html")
            let text = try? String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            webView.loadHTMLString(text!, baseURL: nil)
        }
    }

    // End Of Custom bottomfooter


    // rate app
    func rateApp()
    {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xyz/idxyz")!)
    }

    // share app
    func shareApp(_ shareAppText: String,shareAppUrl: String)
    {
        let firstActivityItem  = shareAppText
        let secondActivityItem = shareAppUrl

        print("printing firstActivityItem  \(firstActivityItem)")
        print("printing secondActivityItem  \(secondActivityItem)")


        let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //share product page
    func shareAppPage(_ shareAppPageSubject: String, shareAppPageURL: String)
    {

        print("printing shareAppPageText  \(shareAppPageSubject)")

        let firstActivityItem = shareAppPageSubject


        let secondActivityItem : URL = URL(string: shareAppPageURL)!

        let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //session handling
    func loadFromBaseUrl()
    {
        viewDidLoad()
    }

    func checkUpdate()
    {
        let nsObject : AnyObject! = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as AnyObject!

        let localVersion  = nsObject as! String

        let numberFromString = (localVersion as NSString).doubleValue

        print("ios App version "+localVersion)

        let UpdateUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "example.com?actionname=MobileAppAjaxHandler.getIOSMobileAppVersion")!

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:UpdateUrl as URL)

        let queue: OperationQueue = OperationQueue()

        // Sending Asynchronous request using NSURLConnection

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler:{(response:URLResponse?, responseData:Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in

            if error != nil
            {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }
            else
            {
                //Converting data to String

                let responseStr = NSString(data: responseData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                print("response of remote Ios version  ========"+(responseStr! as String))

                let serverVersion = responseStr! as String

                let numfromstr = (serverVersion as NSString).doubleValue
                if numfromstr > numberFromString
                {
                    let updateBox = UIAlertController(title: "Update App", message: "App update is available on app store", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    updateBox.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xyz/idxyz")!)
                    }))
                    updateBox.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

                    }))
                    self.present(updateBox, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        print("inside view WillAppear for Portrait orientation");

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate : Bool
    {
        print("shouldAutorotate return false");
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
        print("supportedInterfaceOrientations");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
     {
     let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_)-> Void in
     completionHandler()
     }))
     self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_)-> Void in
            completionHandler(true)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (_)-> Void in
            completionHandler(false)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

My Xcode version is 9.2 and this is the only file i have got. Any small help will be appreciated

Comment: You have use frame to set layout.safe area is related to Autolayout, so you need to set the constraint programatically.

Comment: can you please provide any material, which will help me to set the constraint programatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add constraints programmatically using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/how-to-add-constraints-programmatically-using-swift)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to do `autolayout` using the `layout anchors` instead of `frame` to your custom `WKWebView`.

```
let containerViewHeight: CGFloat = 45

webView = WKWebView()//(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight))
view.addSubview(webView)

webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -containerViewHeight).isActive = true

containerView = WKWebView()//(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width:screenWidth, height:screenHeight))
view.addSubview(containerView)

containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

For the glance of safeArea region I've added the below image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you 1000 times, your solution work perfectly for top container. I have separate container at bottom how to place it in safe area. Name of bottom container is containerView

Comment: can you please tell me how to place another container at bottom of safe area

Comment: containerView is being placed at bottom but it is not in safe area.

Comment: I'm sorry. You didn't ask the same? My bad. Will update answer soon

Comment: Answer has been updated plz check once. Let me know still I miss some thing 

Comment: thanks you 10,000 times. your solution work just perfectly for me.

Comment: why we need extra container view for assign WebView into this?