# Cocoa Swift: Subview not resizing with superview

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller, xcode10.2

I'm adding a subview(`NSView`), here is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.view.needsDisplay = true
    let newView = NSView()
    newView.autoresizesSubviews = true
    newView.frame = view.bounds
    newView.wantsLayer = true
    newView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
    view.addSubview(newView)
}
```

And it works fine

[image]
But when I resize the window the subview is not resizing.

[image]

Any of you knows why or how can make the subview resize with superview?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: you may need to set the autolayout bounds or create a function to update the subview bounds in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @jessi, can you post an code example ?

Comment: If you are using the Interface builder, set constraints between the subview and the newview to be the same (you can do this by anchoring the edges or by anchoring the h and w). Programmatically, I won't reinvent the wheel here - see examples from this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/how-to-add-constraints-programmatically-using-swift

Comment: @jessi those examples in the link you mention is just adding constraints but doesn't help if the super view is been resize

Comment: I don't understand. As long as the view constraints are related to the superview constraints and you call layoutifneeded, any changes in the superview should cascade to its subview(s)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set `view.autoresizesSubviews` to `true`, which tells `view` to resize each of its subviews. But you also have to specify how you want each subview to be resized. You do that by setting the subview's `autoresizingMask`. Since you want the subview's `frame` to continue to match the superview's `bounds`, you want the subview's `width` and `height` to be flexible, and you want its X and Y margins to be fixed (at zero). Thus:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.view.needsDisplay = true
    let newView = NSView()

    // The following line had no effect on the layout of newView in view,
    // so I have commented it out.
    // newView.autoresizesSubviews = true

    newView.frame = view.bounds

    // The following line tells view to resize newView so that newView.frame
    // stays equal to view.bounds.
    newView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]

    newView.wantsLayer = true
    newView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
    view.addSubview(newView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix for this issue:

```
override func viewWillLayout() {
        super.viewWillLayout()
        newView.frame = view.bounds

    }
```