# Resizing NSScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, nsscrollview

How can I resize NSScrollView using Swift?

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad {
        scrollView.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 340, y: 537))
        scrollView.setFrameSize(CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: 102.0))
    }

}
```

The above code works only if there are no constraints set. But, without constraints, the ScrollView doesn't stay in place when the window is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this worked for me since my ScrollView was positioned on the top left:

```
scrollView.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: self.view.frame.minX + 340, y: self.view.frame.maxY - 172))
scrollView.setFrameSize(CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: 102.0))
```

And the below image shows the settings used in Size Inspector to enable auto resize and also to stay to the top-left of the window.

[image: ScrollView Size Inspector]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set the *document* size (scrollable area) of a `NSScrollView`,  then all we need to do is set the document view's size.

> **Note:** This assumes there are no constraints on the document view.

```swift
scrollView.documentView?.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 576, height: 56))
```

If you are trying to scroll to a specific region, see [`scrollToVisible(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483811-scrolltovisible).

Comment: Hey! I just updated my question, how can I include constrains and make it work the same time? I just need it to stay in place and auto resize when window is resized. The framesize is set to only change it's height. I want rest of it's attributes to auto resize.

Comment: I don’t understand. If you’re using constraints, then you can just use them to constrain the width to a constant value or to an aspect ratio with respect to the height, etc.. You can [programmatically add additional constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181982) too.

Comment: So, I wanted to increase the height of the ScrollView towards the bottom without using any constraints.

Comment: Like an overscroll?

Comment: Umm, I don't know what overscroll means but just increase the height towards the origin of the Y-axis. So had to reset the y-axis from the top of the screen and change the height. Anyway thanks for your help!