# Swift: autolayout programmatically of image

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

In my Swift app i have inserted an image like this:

```
let ImageNavig = "5.jpg"
        let image1 = UIImage(named: ImageNavig)
        let image1View = UIImageView(image: image1!)
        let yCenter1 = self.view.center.y
        let Image1Size = CGPoint(x: 420, y: 240)
        image1View.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: Image1Size.x, height: Image1Size.y)
        view.addSubview(image1View)
```

but, when I run the project with older Iphone the results is this:
[image]

how can I insert autolayout programmatically without storyboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add constraints programmatically using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/how-to-add-constraints-programmatically-using-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have issue of image width in old iphones then it is because, you have given fix width to the image , use below code it will take width dynamically as per iphone width

```
let Image1Size = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 240)
```

instead of

```
let Image1Size = CGPoint(x: 420, y: 240)
```