# How to programmatically add constraints to a stackView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I programmatically created a stackView with a UISegmentedControl and a Map with a MKMapView. I am using CGRect to size and place the frame of the stackView in the interface but when I switch the device simulator the stackView moves since it does not have any constraints. I usually use the StoryBoard to add constraints to anything but have never programmatically done it my self. I have seen other examples here in Stack Overflow but so far It doesn't help with what it is that I am trying to do.
Here is my code showing how I am displaying it in the viewDidLoad(). If someone could explain how to add constraints programmatically so that the stackView covers 1/4 of the screen Y axis:547 please and thank you.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class SampleViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let paddedStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [segmentedControl])
    paddedStackView.layoutMargins = .init(top: 12, left: 12, bottom: 6, right: 12)
    paddedStackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
        paddedStackView, map
        ])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    
    stackView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 547, width: 390, height: 350)

}

let map = MKMapView()

let segmentedControl:UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Arriving", "Leaving"])
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentControl), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc
}()

  @objc func handleSegmentControl(){
    
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        print("Entered Destination")
    case 1:
        print("Exited Destination")
    default:
        print("Error")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how to convert this:

```
stackView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 547, width: 390, height: 350)
```

and make the height `1/4 of the screen` instead of 350

Converting this request into auto layout constraints would go something like this

```
private func configureStackView()
{
    let paddedStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [segmentedControl])
    paddedStackView.layoutMargins = .init(top: 12,
                                          left: 12,
                                          bottom: 6,
                                          right: 12)
    
    paddedStackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [paddedStackView, map])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    
    // AUTO LAYOUT
    
    // This is important for using auto layout
    // Setting this to false means the frame is ignored
    // So sizing and positioning should be set by NSLayoutConstraints
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // Add the view to its parent before adding any constraints
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    
    // Add constraints equivalent to:
    // CGRect(x: 0, y: 547, width: 390, height: 350)
    view.addConstraints([
        // this is x origin
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        
        // this is y origin
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,
                                       constant: 547),
        
        // this is the width
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 390),
        
        // this is height, thanks to @flanker for this update
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,
                                          multiplier: 0.75)
    ])
}
```

This should give you what you are looking for.

With that being said, you probably want to check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180822/how-to-add-constraints-programmatically-using-swift) as there are different ways to add auto layout constraints programmatically so see which way you prefer

**Update with screenshot**

The above configuration gives something like this

[image: Programmatically create UIStackView with auto layout constraints swift iOS]

Comment: While generally ok, using a constant for the height could cause problems if screen orientation or size (think iPad) changes.  I'd prefer calculating it in the constraint, probably using the parent views constraint and a multiplier 0f 0.75, so it's always correct when constraints are reapplied.

Comment: @flanker - thanks for that tip and I agree with you, that is a better way to do things than my initial solution. I have updated the answer with this - thanks again !

Comment: @ShawnFrank Everything works well except the map view does not show only the segmented control when setting the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.

Comment: @Chamoy - there was a small bug with the height anchor, I have updated it with a screenshot, please use the latest code above.

Comment: @ShawnFrank It works perfectly fine now and thank you for the comments in your code, helped me understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //MARK: UIStackView
    
    let stackview = UIStackView()
    stackview.axis = .vertical
    stackview.spacing = 2
    stackview.distribution = .fill
    
    //MARK: Stackview Elements
    let view_left = UIView()
    let view_right = UIView()
    
    //MARK: initial added View
    stackview.addArrangedSubview(view_left)
    stackview.addArrangedSubview(view_right)
    
    //MARK: remove Run time stack elements
    
    for view in stackview.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
   //MARK: Again assign values Run time
    
    stackview.insertArrangedSubview(view_right, at: 0)
    stackview.insertArrangedSubview(view_left, at: 1)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation why you think this is a good solution.